# Using boost::mutex - implicitly deleted error (because the default definition would be ill-formed)

Tags: c++, boost

I have class looks as follows in `.h` file  (Header)

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

class MyClass{

    private:
        boost::mutex bPoolMtx_;

        // ... other vars
    public:
        // public vars and methods

}
```

I get the following error trying to build/ compile.

```
MyClass.h:38:7: note: ‘MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
MyClass.h:38:7: error: use of deleted function ‘boost::mutex::mutex(const boost::mutex&)’
```

I don't use the mutex at all in the cpp file yet. When I comment out the `boost::mutex` line it builds fine. What is going on?

Comment: It means the mutex is not copyable. You are probably copying `MyClass` instances somewhere. This requires the data members to be copyable.

Comment: Exactly. Try to disable copying for `MyClass`, and see what happens then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default copy constructor generated by the compiler copies all data members by default. Your use of `boost::mutex` throws an error because the mutex isn't copyable.

You can write your own copy constructor that doesn't attempt to copy the mutex or simply delete the copy constructor for `MyClass`.

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

class MyClass{
    private:
        boost::mutex bPoolMtx_;

        // ... other vars
    public:
        // public vars and methods
        MyClass(const MyClass&) = delete;
}
```

Comment: Does this mean I cannot copy MyClass if I want to use mutex?  for example having a vector<MyClass> somewhere?

Comment: You need to write your own copy constructor that copies the data but constructs a new mutex.

Comment: I see. Appreciate your response, I fixed it now by storing a pointer instead since the copying was not needed. Thanks

Comment: "Appreciate your response, I fixed it now by storing a pointer instead since the copying was not needed." - 8-| ... danger lurks.

Comment: Using a pointer means that the copy and the original will lock on the same mutex (i.e., when a method call on the original takes the mutex, all internally synchronized method calls on the copy will block too). That's probably not a good idea.

Comment: The pointer of the class I store is a single instance so I don't have any of the problems you guys mention. Thanks for your comments though, appreciated.