# Selection of istream from cin or file with ternary operator

Tags: c++, iostream

I would like to have a member variable of a class which stores the input stream depending on a string entered by the user. eg.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class myInput {
public:
    myInput(std::string file_name);
    myInput() = delete;

protected:
    std::istream& in_data;
};
 
myInput::myInput(std::string file_name)
    : in_data((file_name == "-") ? std::cin : std::ifstream(file_name)){}

void main() {
    myInput("file.txt");
}
```

However I am receiving the following errors

```
error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_istream(const std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits]’
error: ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_istream(const std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits]’ is protected within this context
```

I have also tried creating the `ifstream` object separately and assigning that to `in_data`, but encounter similar problems. Why is this?

Comment: I believe you are missing initialization for in_data in your myInput constructor... refer to the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966698/error-use-of-deleted-function

Comment: Hint: you have to store the **object** ifstream if the case the string is not "-".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::istream` does not allow you to do something like `in_data = std::cin` or `in_data = std::ifstream("file.txt")` as the assignment operator is deleted.

An alternate solution is to use a pointer to `std::istream`.

```cpp
class myInput {
public:
    myInput(std::string file_name);
    virtual ~myInput() { if (bIsHeapAllocated) delete in_data; } // delete the heap allocation if done.
    myInput() = delete;

protected:
    std::istream* in_data = nullptr;
    bool bIsHeapAllocated = false;    // You can make this a private member if you don't want your inherited classes knowing this.
};

myInput::myInput(std::string file_name)
{
    if (file_name == "-")
        in_data = &std::cin;
    else
        in_data = new std::ifstream(file_name), bIsHeapAllocated = true;    // Allocate the ifstream in heap
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the `#include <iostream>` header file first in your program it shouldn't be on the second line

Comment: While this is indeed an issue with the code of op, it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue. Also my code (in the full implementation) is auto-formatted. It actually puts `iostream` after `fstream` for some reason

Comment: It's a good practice to include `iostream` at first, but if not added at first, it doesn't cause any error either.