# CPP: Use of deleted function

Tags: c++

I am trying to sort a vector that contains custom `struct` entries using a lambda function in c++ . But I get prompted the following error message

> error: use of deleted function ‘dummy_struct& dummy_struct::operator=(const dummy_struct&)

The code looks like the following:

```
#include <regex>

struct dummy_struct
{
    dummy_struct(std::string name, int64_t value_a) :
        name(name),
        value_a(value_a)
    {}
    
    const std::string name;
    const int64_t value_a;
    
    int ExtractNumberFromName(std::regex key)
    {
        int retval;
        std::cmatch match;
        std::regex_search(this->name.c_str(),match,key);
        retval=std::stoi(match[0],nullptr);
        return retval;
    }
    
};


void SortByCustomKey(const std::vector<dummy_struct> collection, std::regex key)
{

    auto compare = [key](dummy_struct a, dummy_struct b)
    {
        return a.ExtractNumberFromName(key) > b.ExtractNumberFromName(key)
    };
    
    std::sort(std::begin(collection),std::end(collection),compare);

}

int main()
{

    std::vector<dummy_struct> test;
    
    test.push_back(dummy_struct("Entry[1]",1));
    test.push_back(dummy_struct("Entry[2]",2));
    test.push_back(dummy_struct("Entry[3]",3));
    
    SortByCustomKey(test,std::regex("[0-9]+"));
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: all your fields are `const` so how assignment could do anything? One `const` field is enough to prevent compiler from generating default implementation of assignment operator.

Comment: You should pass non-trivial parameters by references, currently your sort works on a copy of the `test` vector.

Comment: @MarekR I used the ```const``` notation because the fields shall not be changed once initialized. Does this mean that by invoking the ```sort``` I am creating issues due to values being changed?

Comment: See [doc of std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort): `The type of dereferenced RandomIt must meet the requirements of MoveAssignable and MoveConstructible.`

Comment: If the fields shall not be changed under any circumstances, how would copy or move assignment be possible?

Comment: You can also check a similar post [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966698/error-use-of-deleted-function/5966859)

Comment: @MarekR so this means, that if I use a ```const``` at any point in my struct fields, I cannot use functions like e.g., ```std::sort``` due to these criteria being not met. So the solution is to mark the fields as non ```const``` ?

Comment: @Broxigar Correct. `const` member variables are painful :-) Just make them `private` and don't change them - unless copy or move assignment is being done.

Comment: I see. Much appreciated guys. 

@TedLyngmo yes...they are..........

Comment: @Broxigar yes and no. If you have one `const` filed then compiler will not generate default assign operator, but it is possible to define own assign operator. In your context it doesn't make seance, so just drop `const`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

std::sort sorts vector by swapping it's elements in place.

This requires for your class to implement [copy assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment) (or move assignment), which compiler won't generate for you due to `const` fields in the class. For your example the only solution seems to remove the `const` qualifiers from the fields. If you don't want them to be modified just make them `private` and don't provide (public) setters.
If they absolutely must stay there and you just want to get your values in sorted order you can use a different structure or store pointers in the vector.

Another solution is to write a custom `swap` implementation for your class that would `const_cast` away the qualifiers of the fields for the purpose of the assignment, although this is usually a bad code smell.