# error: use of deleted function 'Hund4::Hund4()'

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I am a newbie in C++. I wrote this code to understand the difference between `public`, `protected` and `private`. The problem is, when I create an object of `Hund4`, I get this error:

> use of deleted function

This error is in the last line.

Can you please help me to solve this problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Tier
{
public:
    void wieMachtDasTier()
    {
        cout << "Hello\n";
    }

protected:
    void foo()
    {
        cout << "foo\n";
    }

private:
    void baz()
    {
        cout << "baz\n";
    }
};

class Hund: public Tier
{
private:
    string name;

public:
    Hund(string newname):name(newname){}

    string getname()
    {
        return this->name;
    }

    void test()
    {
        foo();
    }
};

class Hund2: protected Tier
{
public:
    void test()
    {
        foo();
    }
};

class Hund3: private Tier
{
public:
    void test()
    {
        foo();
    }
};

class Hund4 : public Hund
{

};

int main()
{
    Hund ace("ace");
    ace.wieMachtDasTier();
    Tier Haustier;
    ace.test();
    Hund2 ace2;
    ace2.test();
    Hund3 ace3;
    ace3.test();
    Hund4 ace4;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When asking questions about build errors, first please make sure that your [mre] really is minimal. Secondly copy-paste (as text) the full and complete build log into the question itself. If you look through it there may even be hints and information that helps you solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: use of deleted function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966698/error-use-of-deleted-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Hund` class that `Hund4` derives from has no default constructor, so `Hund4` has no default constructor. You can construct a `Hund4` from a `std::string` or a `Hund`, though:

```
Hund4 ace4(std::string{"ace4"});
Hund4 ace4(Hund{"ace4"});

using std::literals;
Hund4 ace("Waldi"s);
```

For some reason, somebody else please explain why a `const char *` is sufficient for `Hund` but doesn't work for `Hund4`.

Or, you have to give `Hund4` a constructor:

```
class Hund4 : public Hund
{
  public:
    Hund4(string newname) : Hund(newname) { }
};

Hund4 ace4("ace4");
```

Comment: Hi Goswin! Thank you for your answer! The problem is that i tried it but this time i get another error which is 'no matching function for call to Hund4::(const char[5])'
For the other classes i didn't define the objects that way. For example i wrote only Hund3 ace3; and it worked. I am kinda confused why it didnt work for Hund4.

Comment: @The_Beginner this variant is closer to correct than what you currently have. In another few hours you can, and should if you haven't figured it out by then, ask a question about it.

Comment: @goswin von Brederlow i created a constructor now for the class Hund4 as you mentioned and it worked. My question is: Why could i create an object of the other classes without the constructor (for example Hund2 and Hund3) but for the class Hund4 it was necessary to add a constructor. So is it because the class Hund4 inherited the class Hund, which has a constructor and the other classes (Hund2 and Hund3) inherited the class Tier, which doesent have a constructor?

Comment: @The_Beginner `Hund2` and `Hund3` both have a compiler-generated default constructor, because they derive from `Tier` which has a compiler-generated default constructor. `Hund` has a user-defined constructor, so it does not have a compiler-generated default constructor, and so neither does `Hund4`, either. If you want `Hund4` to be default-constructable, it needs its own user-defined default constructor that calls `Hund`'s non-default constructor, eg: `Hund4() : Hund("") { }` or `Hund4(string newname = "") : Hund(newname) { }`.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Thank you very much that explains a lot! But i still have another question: if i want Hund4 to be default-constructable then i have to remove the user-defined constructor from Hund? how can make its own user-defined default constructor that calls Hund' s non-default constructor?

Comment: @The_Beginner No, you can just give the Hund a default name like in: `Hund4() : Hund("") { }` or `Hund4(string newname = "") : Hund(newname) { }`. Or add a default name in `Hund(string newname = "<nameless dog>") ...`.

Comment: @Goswin von Brederlow Thanks a lot!

Comment: Using `std::string` literals works too.

Answer (score 1):

`Tier` has no *user-declared* constructors, and `std::string` is default-constructable, so `Tier` has a *compiler-generated* default constructor.

`Hund2` and `Hund3` derive from `Tier`, have no *user-declared* constructors, and do not have any non-default-constructable data members, so they have *compiler-generated* default constructors as well.

`Hund`, on the other hand, has a *user-declared* constructor, so it does not have a *compiler-generated* default constructor.

`Hund4` has no *user-declared* constructors, but `Hund` is not default-constructable, so `Hund4` does not have a *compiler-generated* default constructor.

So, if you want `Hund4` to be default-constructable, you need to either:

- make `Hund` default-constructable, eg:

  ```
  class Hund: public Tier
  {
  private:
      string name;

  public:
      Hund() {}
      Hund(string newname) : name(newname) {}

      // or:
      // Hund(string newname = "") : name(newname) {}

      ...
  };
  ```
- give `Hund4` its own *user-declared* default constructor, which calls `Hund`'s non-default constructor, eg:

  ```
  class Hund4 : public Hund
  {
  public:
      Hund4() : Hund("") { }

      // or:
      // Hund4(string newname = "") : Hund(newname) { }
  };
  ```

Comment: you are a GOD :D Thanks!